# Analyzing Magnus effect from ground frame

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, projectile, bernoulli-equation

How can we explain Magnus effect to the path deviation of a spinning ball assuming the air is still (looking from ground frame)?
I understand that we can use bernoulli principle from ball's frame, but why can't we use bernoulli principle in ground frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernoulli's principle assumes a steady flow. The flow is steady in the reference frame of the ball, but is unsteady in the lab frame.

Comment: How can steady flow in one frame be unsteady in another?

Comment: The flow is unsteady if the velocity field $u$ changes with time at a fixed position $x$ (i.e $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \neq 0$). The coordinate $x$ is defined differently in the two frames, so that in the ball frame, we have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$, while in the lab frame $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \neq 0$.